# Order list of names with Lua

Tags: luatex, sorting, lua

I want to define a command using `\directlua` that looks something like:

```
\sort{c, b, a}
```

and outputs `a, b, c` to the document.

Answer (score 7):

In ConTeXt you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

```
\def\sort#1{%
  \ctxlua{
    context(
      table.concat(
        table.sorted(
          utilities.parsers.settings_to_array([[#1]]) ) , ", " ) )
}}

\starttext

\sort{c, b, a}

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

You can also use it with LaTeX by including the appropriate Lua headers from ConTeXt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-lpeg.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-sto.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-prs.lua"))
}

\def\sort#1{%
  \directlua{\unexpanded{
    tex.sprint(
      table.concat(
        table.sorted(
          utilities.parsers.settings_to_array([[#1]]) ) , ", " ) )
}}}

\begin{document}

\sort{c, b, a}

\end{document}
```

The output is similar.

---

To omit empty entries (empty string) one has to write one additional helper function, which I could not find in ConTeXt.  However, multiple empty entries side by side seem to confuse at least one of the functions, i.e. `\sort{,,,,a}` will produce spurious commas.

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-lpeg.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-string.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-sto.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-prs.lua"))

function table.strip_empty(tab)
    for k, v in pairs(tab) do
        if ( string.strip(v) == "" ) then
            table.remove(tab, k)
        end
    end
    return tab
end
}

\def\sort#1{%
  \directlua{\unexpanded{
    tex.sprint(
      table.concat(
        table.sorted(
          table.strip_empty(
            utilities.parsers.settings_to_array([[#1]]) ) ) , ", " ) )
}}}

\begin{document}

\sort{, d, , f, c, b, a, }

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Is there a way to modify the routines to automatically delete any leading commas (say, because the command was `\sort{c, ,b, a,}`)?

Comment: @Mico See updated answer.  Unfortunately, I could not find a remove function in ConTeXt.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution. The main Lua function, called `dojob`, converts the input string into a Lua table (via a call to an auxiliary Lua function called `string_to_table`), performs a simple sort, and outputs the table elements as a string, with the elements separated by "`,`" ("comma&space"). Any leading or trailing whitespace characters and commas are discarded automtically.

The Lua function `dojob` may be accessed from within the body of a LaTeX document via the LaTeX macro called `\sort`.

Aside: Much of the Lua code in the `string_to_table` function was obtained from [this site](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin). (Look for the header "Method: Using only string.gsub" for more details on how the code works.) For good measure, I added a routine that removes leading and trailing whitespace from the table entries.

The sorting routine is simple. I trust your comma-separated list isn't so long as to require a more efficient sorting algorithm (e.g., QuickSort) in order to avoid getting bogged down.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function string_to_table (str)
   sep = ","
   fields = {}
   str:gsub( "([^"..sep.."]*)" .. sep , 
               function(c) 
                 c = string.gsub ( c, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1" )
                 table.insert (fields, c)   
               end)
   return fields
end
function dojob ( s )
   -- append "," (if needed) to end of string
   if (string.sub(s,-1) == ",") then else s = s.."," end 
   -- convert string to table
   t = string_to_table ( s , "," )
   -- sort the table entries
   table.sort ( t , function(a,b) return a<b end)
   -- convert table to string, with items separated by commas
   s = table.concat ( t, ", " )
   -- remove any leading whitespace and comma characters, output the string
   tex.sprint ( (string.gsub( s, "^[,%s]*(.*)$", "%1" ) ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\sort[1]{\directlua{dojob(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\sort{c, b, a}

\sort{Carla , Eric , Anna Michelle, Brenda  , Daniel}

\sort{Eric,Carla,Brenda,Anna Michelle,Daniel,,}

\sort{aaa,15}
\end{document}
```